# Excel VBA Solver function error

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have A VBA code that seems to work well with a PC, but when I try to run the same code on a Mac it doesn't work properly.  The code is designed to start at a designated column, in this case 3.  The code is used to find the minimum variance frontier.  Below is a sample of the sheet with the column and row reference.

```
 Row                         Col3     Col4    Col5.....
 26      WeightAssetA         .3
 27      WeightAssetB         .3
 28      WeightAssetC         .2
 29      WeightAssetD         .2
 30            Sum            1
 31      Target Return        .05   
 32      Variance
 33
 34      Expected Return
```

The code is designed to find the minimum of row 32, variance, by changing rows 26 thru 29.  The constraints are that row 30 must equal 1 (sum of 26:29) and match the target return.  Below is my current code.  When I run the it seems to be looping through each column but of the 26 columns only the column which contains the very lowest variance is changed to include the updated security weights.

Any suggestions on why it's looping through each column but not updating each column with the correct weights, only the one with the lowest variance?  Thanks!

```
Sub Optimizer()
'
' Frontier Macro
' Macro for Developing Portfolio Frontier
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
'
Dim col As Integer

For col = 3 To 29

   SolverReset

   SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=False

   SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(32, col), MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=Range(Cells(26, col), Cells(29, col))

   SolverAdd CellRef:=Cells(30, col), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"

   SolverAdd CellRef:=Cells(31, col), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=Cells(31, col)


   SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: email me the complete file and I will look at it for you